# How to tell Entity Framework Core 5 that two entities are not related?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship, .net-5, invalidoperationexception

I am using the code first approach and have two entities that are not related

```
[table("state")]
public class StateCodeDTO {
    [Key]
    [column("state_code")
    string StateCode { get; set; }
   
    [column("state_name")]
    string StateName { get; set; }
}

[table("location")]
public class LocationDTO {
    [Key]
    [column("id")
    int Id { get; set; }
   
    [column("location_name")]
    string Location_Name { get; set; }
}
```

I might have created a query where I mistakenly included both entities. I don't recall exactly what I did but it was an error. Now I am stuck
with `Entity Framework` thinking there is a relationship between the two tables. I my context I have the following DbSets:

```
public DbSet<LocationDTO> LocationInformation { get; set; }
public DbSet<StateCodeDTO> StateCode { get; set; }
```

If I issue the following call:

```
var stateDTOs = _dbContext.StateCode.ToList();
```

I have the dreaded `Invalid column name` exception

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'LocationDTOId'.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, bool callerHasConnectionLock, bool asyncClose)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, out bool dataReady)

Note that everything was working fine until I made that invalid query which seemed to have put everything in a tailspin. I don't think it is relevant what I did, I just need a way to tell `Entity Framework` that these two entities are not related. It seems like it is applying the `Code First` convention *ClassNameKey* to the location table and is thinking that `LocationDTOId` is a foreign key in the state table. This could not be further from the truth.

`How can I tell Entity Framework that these entities are unrelated?`

Comment: i'm guessing ef is validating its model, not that they are related.

Comment: Is there a way I can around that?

Comment: Can you show your dbcontext fluent api?

Comment: *"How can I tell Entity Framework that these entities are unrelated?"* - By finding and correcting the place where you actually are telling EF that they **are** related. With what you have shown there is no way it could happen. Also it could not happen by creating query. However, some fluent configuration call inside `OnModelCreating`, or `LocationDTO` class having **collection** navigation property (`IEnumerable`, `ICollection`, `List` etc.) of `StateCodeDTO`  could easily introduce such relationship.

Comment: It is very simple, and has no related information

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerContactDTO>().HasNoKey();
        }

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Ivan. I am looking at my navigation properties.

Comment: Have you run a migration? Perhaps you changed something and don't realize it and adding a new  migration will expose and fix it

Comment: Did you check your DB? It could be there by mistake. You will have to repeat  init migration then.

Comment: @IvanStoev There was a relationship. There was a
```Collections<StatCodeDTO> States { get; set; }``` in the ```LocationDTO``` entity. It was working until someone introduced the Fluent API there unbeknownst to me.  The ```StateCodeDTO``` entity is for reading purposes and the ```LocationDTO``` has a one-to-many relationship to another entity that holds the state ID and the Location ID. To get around the problem I added ```HasNoKey``` for ```StateCodeDTO```` in Fluent API while I figure out the most efficient way to load up the states in the States navigation properties.

Good pointer